# CSV transfer from SFTP server to S3 via WinSCP

Tags: amazon-s3, sftp, winscp

My work uses WinSCP for SFTP transfers. We have some data coming in this way each week and I would like to get it into an S3 bucket. We want to automate this transferring by use of a cron job or some other way like this.

I know there are AWS tools, but they cost money and money can't be spent. We also do not have an ETL tool like Alteryx, otherwise I would use it. Nothing on the internet gives a lot of detail about transfering files from SFTP server to another server. Mostly reading how to transfer from server to local. 
Below is the code I have found.

Can this WinSCP commands be used to transfer to S3 bucket somehow at the 'put:'? (I cannot use the generator like other posts have said because I do not have access to our AWS or any buckets, yet.) This is all about proving a concept.

```
# Connect to SFTP server using a password
    open sftp://user:password@example.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...="
# Upload file (THIS IS WHERE I WOULD WANT S3 PATH SYNTAX)
    put d:\examplefile.txt /home/user/       
# Exit WinSCP
    Exit
```

Once I have this command we can then create a Windows schedule task, from what I read. This would automate where the file is and we can then do more with the file where SFTP servers limit us.

Comment: Thank you @MartinPrikryl, that was my fear. I noticed it was very easy to run a job from sever to local machine, but noticed it didn't seem possible to go from server to S3. I guess I could just run two jobs each week to get it to S3 and that shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are asking how to transfer files directly from SFTP server to S3 using a script running on yet another machine.

It's not possible (unless AWS has a feature for that, but then it won't be free). You have to download the files from SFTP server and then upload them to S3.

With [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting), you can do it with a script like:

```
open sftp://username:password@sftp.example.com/
get /sftp/path/*
exit

open s3://accesskey:secretkey@s3.amazonaws.com/
put * /bucket/
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your bucket on your server with "s3fs" "fuse" like an normal harddisc.